# Change GNOME Calendar color in top panel Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, calendar

I've just updated to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04. I am using Flat Remix GNOME Theme, but GNOME Calendar in the top panel didn't change its color, now it looks like this:
[image: GNOME Calendar in top panel]

When I had Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME Calendar in the top panel took theme's colors and it was black as well. How can I fix it now?

I've installed it from [here](https://github.com/daniruiz/flat-remix-gnome) putting all files in `~/.themes` and then just selected the theme in GNOME Tweaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not get "Flat Remix GNOME" theme from the link you provided.. It has lot of themes..

for testing purpose.. I choose Flat-Remix-Blue

[image]

open the file

```
gedit $HOME/.themes/Flat-Remix-Blue/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
```

search for "calendarArea"

```
#calendarArea {
  padding: 0; }

.datemenu-calendar-column {
  spacing: 6px;
  border: 0 solid #d9d9d9;
  padding: 0 12px; }
  .datemenu-calendar-column:ltr {
    background-color: yellow; # Have added this line.. Change the color you want..
    margin-right: 8px;
    border-left-width: 1px; }
  .datemenu-calendar-column:rtl {
    margin-left: 8px;
    border-right-width: 1px; }
  .datemenu-calendar-column .datemenu-displays-box {
    spacing: 6px; }
```

Change color yellow with your required color..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to what the OP is asking in the Adapta Nokto Maia theme. Just like on OP's picture, it wasn't the `calendar-column` color that was off, but the calendar itself. So based on `UnKNOWn`'s answer, I added `background-color: transparent` to the `.calendar {` section:

```css
#calendarArea { padding: 0.75em 1em; }

.calendar { margin-bottom: 1em; background-color: transparent; }
```

That made the calendar color match the already correct `column` color:
[image: Fixed calendar]